# SMIME encryption using openssl , decrypting with java bouncy castle fails

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, smime

Hi i have an application where i generate key pair and x509 certificate, i then use the public key (key.pem) and use openssl to encrypt my data to smime format as shown.

```
openssl smime -encrypt -out encrypted_smime.p7m -in token.json out form SMIME key.pem
```

the encrypted file looks like

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

......
```

after this i take this and give it as an input to my application as serverTokenBytes which tries decrypting it using this logic.

```
   public static String decryptServerToken(final byte[] serverTokenBytes, final X509Certificate certificate, final PrivateKey privateKey) {
        try {
            final RecipientId recId = new JceKeyTransRecipientId(certificate);
            final Properties props = System.getProperties();
            final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session, new ByteArrayInputStream(serverTokenBytes));
            if (msg.getSize() <= 0 || !(msg.isMimeType("application/pkcs7-mime") || msg.isMimeType("application/x-pkcs7-mime"))) {
                // log error...and throw
            }
            final SMIMEEnveloped m = new SMIMEEnveloped(msg);
            final RecipientInformationStore recipients = m.getRecipientInfos();

            final RecipientInformation recipient = recipients.get(recId);
            if (recipient == null) {
                LOG.error("Error in decrypting the uploaded server token file, the certificate serial number used for encryption differ from the one used for decryption");
                return null;
            }
            final MimeBodyPart res = SMIMEUtil.toMimeBodyPart(recipient.getContent(new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(privateKey)));
            return res.getContent().toString();
        } catch (final MessagingException | CMSException | SMIMEException | IOException exn) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error in decrypting the server token", exn);
        }
    }
```

For some reason this does not work and i an getting back a empty String back without an of the errors mentioned in this code.

I wanted to know if 
1. Encrypting with openssl and decrypting with java bouncy castle . Is this ok ?

1. The decryption doesnt fail and just gives me an empty string , any one sees any problem with this code ?

+++++++++++++Update 1 +++++++++++++++**

Well while debugging i see that the data is getting decrypted properly and getting attached to header of MimeBodyPart but then things go bad as shown below.

I have narrowed down to this code which is causing problem .

public MimeBodyPart(InputStream is) throws MessagingException {

```
if (!(is instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) &&
    !(is instanceof BufferedInputStream) &&
    !(is instanceof SharedInputStream))
    is = new BufferedInputStream(is);

headers = new InternetHeaders(is);

if (is instanceof SharedInputStream) {
    SharedInputStream sis = (SharedInputStream)is;
    contentStream = sis.newStream(sis.getPosition(), -1);
} else {
    try {
    content = ASCIIUtility.getBytes(is);
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
    throw new MessagingException("Error reading input stream", ioex);
    }
}
```

and the ASCIIUtility getBytes returns []

```
public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {

int len;
int size = 1024;
byte [] buf;


if (is instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
    size = is.available();
    buf = new byte[size];
    len = is.read(buf, 0, size);
}
else {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    buf = new byte[size];
    while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, size)) != -1)
    bos.write(buf, 0, len);
    buf = bos.toByteArray();
}
return buf;
}
```

the size = is.available(); always returns 0;

+++++++++++++Update 2 +++++++++++++++**
I generated another encrypted message now with using java's BC as a provider.
the difference between the encrypted messages created by these two are like this in terms of header.

Bouncy castle generated encrypted messages:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name="smime.p7m"; smime-type=enveloped-data
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-ID: <621547276.1.1394777375030.JavaMail.abcd@localhost>
```

.....

openssl genarted encrypted message header.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

......

The openssl generated encrypted message when it gets passed to 
final MimeBodyPart res = SMIMEUtil.toMimeBodyPart(...content...) cause the MimeBodyPart headers to be set differently than as compared to when bouncy castle generated message when passed through the same api.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but were you able to solve the problem?